# Find the order of $G=C_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times S_4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Find the order of $G=C_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times S_4 $.

Am I correct in thinking that you simply multiply the order of each component? This would give $|G|=3*5*24=360$

Comment: Correct. For finite groups $G, H$, $|G \times H| = |G||H|$.

Comment: For sure? And we don't have to worry about an overlapping of any groups?

Comment: for finite groups? it works always, just look at the set of elements

Comment: In general for finite groups: $|G_1\times\ldots\times G_n|=|G_1|\cdot\ldots\cdot |G_n|$

Comment: No overlap in a direct product.

Comment: Thank you! I knew my lecturer made a mistake in one of the example sheets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of $G\times H$ is $|G|\|H|$, this is simply because the set of elements of $G\times H$ is the set of ordered pairs $(g,h)$.

Maybe you are confusing external direct product with internal product of subgroups in which the order of $GH$ is $\frac{|G||H|}{|G\cap H|}$. But this is in a different setting.